# Working with .NET properties in Power Shell

Tags: .net, powershell

I'm trying to measure latency using Test-NetConnection.  I've gotten this to work well with Test-Connection, but it's not available everywhere.

Here is what I've done with Test-Connection:

```
PS:>Test-Connection 8.8.8.8 -count 1 | select ResponseTime

ResponseTime
------------
28
```

Test-NetConnection does return a property containing latency.

```
PS:>Test-NetConnection 8.8.8.8

ComputerName           : 8.8.8.8
RemoteAddress          : 8.8.8.8
InterfaceAlias         : eth0
SourceAddress          : REMOVED
PingSucceeded          : True
PingReplyDetails (RTT) : 28 ms
```

But when I try to refer to this property, I don't get the value.

```
PS:>Test-NetConnection 8.8.8.8 | select PingReplyDetails

PingReplyDetails
----------------
System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply
```

How can I get the actual value out of the command?

Comment: Hi, I wonder where `Test-Connection` is not available ?

Comment: @sodawillow - Check your `$PSVersionTable`, as you're likely not on (I think), 3 or 4 when this was introduced.

Comment: For clarity : OP says `Test-Connection` is not available everywhere. It was introduced with PS v2. OTOH I agree that `Test-NetConnection` is newer (introduced in v4). This makes we wonder why OP wants to use the latter instead of the former, since he's worrying about compatibility.

Comment: I'm working on Windows IoT.  It's missing several cmdlets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this... I've broken it down into two steps for a bit more clarity, but you can combine into a single statement on your own if you'd like.

```
$data = Test-NetConnection 8.8.8.8 | select -ExpandProperty PingReplyDetails
$data.RoundtripTime
```

Appears to work for me, as you are going for.  Since your question includes different attempts, I trust you should be able to customize to fit your exact needs.

In short, use `-ExpandProperty` to bring out the details in an object.

Comment: Great! So it's like a sub-property of a property?  To keep it in context with the original way I was doing it, you could get the correct output like so:

`Test-NetConnection 8.8.8.8 | select -ExpandProperty PingReplyDetails | select RoundtripTime`

`RoundtripTime`
`-------------`
`29`

Comment: I intentionally answered this like so, so you could try just doing `$data` (by itself) after the assignment.  There you will see that the RTT had MORE properties to dig deeper into it, yes.  ;)

Answer (score 3):

Well the problem is that `PingReplyDetails (RTT)` is not a real property as you can see with the following command and its output, where this 'property' is missing.

```
PS > Test-NetConnection SomeHost | Get-Member


   TypeName: TestNetConnectionResult

Name                     MemberType Definition                                               
----                     ---------- ----------                                               
Equals                   Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)                           
GetHashCode              Method     int GetHashCode()                                        
GetType                  Method     type GetType()                                           
ToString                 Method     string ToString()                                        
AllNameResolutionResults Property   System.Object AllNameResolutionResults {get;set;}        
BasicNameResolution      Property   System.Object BasicNameResolution {get;set;}             
ComputerName             Property   string ComputerName {get;set;}                           
Detailed                 Property   bool Detailed {get;set;}                                 
DNSOnlyRecords           Property   System.Object DNSOnlyRecords {get;set;}                  
InterfaceAlias           Property   string InterfaceAlias {get;set;}                         
InterfaceDescription     Property   string InterfaceDescription {get;set;}                   
InterfaceIndex           Property   uint32 InterfaceIndex {get;set;}                         
IsAdmin                  Property   bool IsAdmin {get;set;}                                  
LLMNRNetbiosRecords      Property   System.Object LLMNRNetbiosRecords {get;set;}             
MatchingIPsecRules       Property   ciminstance[] MatchingIPsecRules {get;set;}              
NameResolutionSucceeded  Property   bool NameResolutionSucceeded {get;set;}                  
NetAdapter               Property   ciminstance NetAdapter {get;set;}                        
NetRoute                 Property   ciminstance NetRoute {get;set;}                          
NetworkIsolationContext  Property   string NetworkIsolationContext {get;set;}                
PingReplyDetails         Property   System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply PingReplyDetai...
PingSucceeded            Property   bool PingSucceeded {get;set;}                            
RemoteAddress            Property   ipaddress RemoteAddress {get;set;}                       
RemotePort               Property   uint32 RemotePort {get;set;}                             
SourceAddress            Property   ciminstance SourceAddress {get;set;}                     
TcpClientSocket          Property   System.Net.Sockets.Socket TcpClientSocket {get;set;}     
TcpTestSucceeded         Property   bool TcpTestSucceeded {get;set;}                         
TraceRoute               Property   string[] TraceRoute {get;set;}
```

As it turns out, it is just a kind of *formatting sugar* which is defined for the result type (TestNetConnectionResult as seen above) of this Cmdlet. The formatting description for this can be retrieved via the following command:

```
Get-FormatData TestNetConnectionResult | `
Select -ExpandProperty FormatViewDefinition | ? Name -eq DefaultView | `
Select -ExpandProperty Control | `
Select -ExpandProperty Entries | `
Select -ExpandProperty Items | ? Label -eq "PingReplyDetails (RTT)" | `
Select -ExpandProperty DisplayEntry | `
Select -ExpandProperty Value
```

which returns

```
$_.PingReplyDetails.RoundTripTime.ToString() + " ms";
```

With that information in place you can do the same as well e.g. with the following:

```
Test-NetConnection 8.8.8.8 | Select @{N = "PingReplyDetails (RTT)"; E = {$_.PingReplyDetails.RoundTripTime.ToString() + " ms"}}
```

Comment: Beat me to it, but great explanation and thorough breakdown for the asker.

Comment: Based on this answer, this was the best (and easiest to read) for me `(Test-NetConnection 8.8.8.8).pingreplydetails | select Roundtriptime `