# Test-NetConnection gives inconsistent results

Tags: c#, powershell

run into an interesting one today.

I have a bunch of code in C# that creates uses Powershell via a RunspacePool.
I feed it commands and it outputs exactly what Powershell would output if you ran Powershell on it's own, each line is a new entry in a List.

The strange thing is, today when trying the "Test-NetConnection" command in the program it has inconsistent results.

Command:

```
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName 'D123' -InformationLevel Detailed
```

D123 is a Windows 7 VM on the same network

Below you can see two results, it appears to be a 50% chance of getting either:

```
Count = 32
[0]: "ComputerName             : D123"
[1]: "RemoteAddress            : fe80::9503:8d01:d690:6c0a%14"
[2]: "PingSucceeded            : True"
[3]: "PingReplyDetails         : System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply"
[4]: "TcpClientSocket          :"
[5]: "TcpTestSucceeded         : False"
[6]: "RemotePort               : 0"
[7]: "TraceRoute               :"
[8]: "Detailed                 : True"
[9]: "InterfaceAlias           : Internal"
[10]: "InterfaceIndex           : 14"
[11]: "InterfaceDescription     : Intel(R) 82574L Gigabit Network Connection #2"
[12]: "NetAdapter               : MSFT_NetAdapter (CreationClassName = "MSFT_NetAdapter", DeviceID ="
[13]: ""{FDA85168-53B0-4F24-ABEB-BDC9F3A29958}", SystemCreationClassName = "CIM_NetworkPort","
[14]: "SystemName = "WIN-IAJUP1S3FL9.testdomain.com")"
[15]: "NetRoute                 : MSFT_NetRoute (InstanceID = "poB:DD9@?55"
[16]: "?55DD55"
[17]: "")"
[18]: "SourceAddress            : MSFT_NetIPAddress (Name = "poB:DDl:pBD?:lDpC:mDmp?o/"
[19]: "?55"
[20]: "?55"
[21]: "55"
[22]: "", CreationClassName = "","
[23]: "SystemCreationClassName = "", SystemName = "")"
[24]: "NameResolutionSucceeded  : True"
[25]: "BasicNameResolution      : {}"
[26]: "LLMNRNetbiosRecords      : {}"
[27]: "DNSOnlyRecords           : {}"
[28]: "AllNameResolutionResults :"
[29]: "IsAdmin                  : True"
[30]: "NetworkIsolationContext  : Private Network"
[31]: "MatchingIPsecRules       :"
```

Or

```
Count = 9
[0]: "ComputerName             : D123"
[1]: "RemoteAddress            : fe80::9503:8d01:d690:6c0a%14"
[2]: "AllNameResolutionResults : 172.16.0.10"
[3]: "fe80::9503:8d01:d690:6c0a"
[4]: "InterfaceAlias           : Internal"
[5]: "SourceAddress            : fe80::b0f8:20b:f90c:cf3e%14"
[6]: "NetRoute (NextHop)       : ::"
[7]: "PingSucceeded            : True"
[8]: "PingReplyDetails (RTT)   : 0 ms"
```

The second block is what it should be returning, it is also what the command shows when running on Powershell.

What i'd like to know is why it is returning so many values, from the looks of it it's returning results for all members in the command and not just the op level ones (if that makes sense, look here: [Working with .NET properties in Power Shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38019258/working-with-net-properties-in-power-shell)), but I have absolutely no idea why.

**EDIT1**: The blocks of output are copy+pastes from Visual Studio, so the Count = 32 is how many lines Powershell passed back and the [number] is the List position.

**EDIT2**: It seems that the more details is coming from adding " | select *" to the command, this is strange though because none of my code does this and it gets the additional details 50% of the time.

Comment: What is the exact command that you are running? Your first block looks like the output from "Test-NetConnection -ComputerName 'D123' -InformationLevel Detailed | Select *". However where is the "Count = 32" coming from?

Comment: Ah sorry I should have said. The Count = 32 is from Visual Studio, the text in the blocks is a copy+paste of the results passed back from Powershell. So the [number] is the List<string> position.
EDIT: Aha, it seems that the more details are from adding " | select *", but it happens randomly.

Comment: @JohnHanley The exact command is "Test-NetConnection -ComputerName 'D123' -InformationLevel Detailed" which on normal Powershell shows the same as the second block.

Comment: Well, this feels a bit buggy. If you want to diagnose further, post the minimal amount of C# code you're using to execute the PowerShell code and attempt reproducing in the simplest case. In the meantime, you could try adding adding a `Select-Object -property <#properties you want#>` and see if that works-around the issue.

Comment: Hi @veefu , thanks for the suggestion. After some further investigation it seems like if I put the command into the main Window Load event then all subsequent ones screw up, if I remove it from the main Window Load event then it works fine. No clue what's happening but i'll see about getting specific properties instead so it's more consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of Veefu and John I looked into my code more.

Unsure why it does this, but whenever I had the Powershell code run in the main Window Load event it would affect all subsequent executions of the same Powershell command.
When moved to a different section of the code it behaved as expected.

Unsure why this was happening but selecting specific properties from the Powershell output is more consistent, so to anyone who looks at this I'd suggest doing as Veefu said in the comments.